# why does this Dart broadcast stream not accept multiple listen calls

Tags: stream, dart, event-listener

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  var dog = Dog();
  showTheDogACat(dog);
  print('outside');
  dog.bark();
}

class Cat{
  void runAway(msg){
    print("$msg I'm running away!");
  }
}

class Dog{  
  var _barkController = StreamController();
  Stream get onBark => _barkController.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  void bark(){
    _barkController.add("woof");
  }
}

showTheDogACat(dog){
  var cat = Cat();
  dog.onBark.listen((event)=>cat.runAway(event));
  dog.onBark.listen((event)=>print(event));       //why Exception: Stream already has subscriber?
  print('inside');
  dog.bark();
}
```

why does the 2nd `dog.onBark.listen` call generate Exception: stream already has subscriber? I thought broadcast streams could have many subscribers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The getter `onBark` invokes `asBroadcastStream` a second time on the `_barkController.stream`. The newly created broadcast-stream will try to bind to the `_barkController.stream` but will fail because there is already a listener.

So yes: broadcast streams may have multiple listeners, but the `asBroadcastStream` method must not be invoked multiple times on a single-subscription stream.

One solution is to cache the result of your first `asBroadcastStream`.

Comment: Does it mean that it is impossible to set up such an event source without having 2 backing class fields and either explicitly instantiating them in ctor, or having getter implemented as `if(_x == null) _x = ctl.stream.asBroadcastStream(); return _x;`? Can't find anything in core API which wraps this awkward pattern.

Comment: Currently (as of May 2013) there aren't any good alternatives. It is something we are looking into.

Comment: Super late to the party, but maybe for future readers: StreamController has a .broadcast() constructor, use that to avoid having to append asBroadcastStream to your stream.